# Does firebase cloud messaging from php need https server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have coded for fire cloud messaging rest api from my php server. It is working well but I 'm not getting any notification in my mobile.

My server is http only. Do we need https server to send notification from server?

Comment: Yes you need to have ssl certificate.

Comment: You don't need an SSL certificate to send an FCM Message. As long as your server can make an HTTP request you should be able to send. Please include more information in your question like, code used to send the message and the response from the FCM server.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/
i have implemented script as it is in this blog.
plz help me out..

thanks you guys for responding...